# Java HttpURLConnection connect using Weak Ciphers

Tags: java, ssl, https, encryption, weak

I am working on a vulnerability scanner in Java to check for websites that allow connections using weak cipher suites. So I would, for example, try to connect using 56 bits "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA" (or other weak ciphers) and if I get say 200 OK, the website is vulnerable. Here is where I am so far:

1- HttpURLConnection works good all the time with default ciphers but if I try to use "System.setProperty() to set a weak cipher, I either get "cipher not supported exception (for most of the cipher suites) or "connection rejected" exception when I try to connect(). I know connection rejected is my answer to the websites that don't accept weak ciphers, but how do I get the actual http reponse header (with rejection code) instead of the exception?

2- I am actually not interested in finding vulnerability on the SSL level (layer 6) but on HTTP level (layer 7) and I know that http header may be deceptive in some instances, but I am OK with that.

In summary, I need something like this to work for Weak Cipher Suites only:

```
        URL url = new URL(ip);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        con.connect();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do I get the actual http reponse
>   header (with rejection code) instead
>   of the exception?

You don't. The SSL connection isn't formed so there is nothing for HTTP headers to be transmitted over. What you get is the SSLException.

> I am actually not interested in
>   finding vulnerability on the SSL level
>   (layer 6) but on HTTP level

This statement doesn't make any sense. The vulnerability exists at the SSL level. There *is* no HTTP(s)-level connection until the SSL connection is complete, and it fails instead.

Comment: EJP ... thanks for the comments. I think you missed my point. SSL vulnerability exists on SSL Layer ... However ... there are cases (and I have seen many of them) where it is compensated on the App Layer. So for example, if you were to run a vulnerability scanner (such as Nussus). It would come back and report the site vulnerable with weak ciphers (after hitting the SSL layer) ... BUT ... when you try to connect it (let's say, through a browser with only weak cipher suites enabled) you will get a response such as "HTTP Error 403.5 - Forbidden: SSL 128 is required to view this resource."

Comment: .. Also, negotiating SSL connection successfully does not guarantee that connection is a success as a whole.

Comment: @sys146: So you need to look at the response code and its text. I suggest you add all that missing information to your question.

Comment: .. Well, I know the answer would be in the response code. My question simply is ... how can I try to connect to a website using HttpsURLConnection with weak ciphers such as "SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA" I don't see any method in HttpsURLConnection Class where I can select the type of cipher I want to use to connect.

Comment: You set the system property. Whether you get an exception or a response code depends on how the other end is built. If it doesn't have that cipher suite enabled you get a handshake exception. If the *application* has a post-handshake test for the cipher strength it can do anything it likes, including HTTP 403. You can't do anything about that from the client end.